# IBM Websphere MQ Not authorised error AMQ8135

Tags: ibm-mq

I have a dev server running IBM Websphere MQ 7.5. The issue is that users while trying to run runmqsc command getting following error :

```
AMQ8135: Not authorized.

No MQSC commands read.
No commands have a syntax error.
All valid MQSC commands were processed.
```

As I went through IBM Documentation, all user who are part of MQM group should be able to run this.

Also I found that all non-domain accounts, ie local accounts who are part of MQM group are able to run commands. But somehow domain accounts are not working, even when they are part of MQM group. I also added these accounts to domain mqm group, still no luck.

I tried running REFRESH SECURITY Command, still no luck.

If anyone can provide some insight in to this , it would be great.

And yes I am a total noob in IBM Websphere.

Comment: Does your queue manager run under a Domain account or a local account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this helps in your case, but i tried below steps and it worked for me.

1. Right click then Properties on MQSeriesServices from Services
2. Change the logon to "Local System Account".
3. Restart the service.

Note: Assuming that MQM is added to user groups.

Comment: Does this work for Domain accounts that are trying to use runmqsc?

Comment: I know its 2 years since your answer, But this did work. Thanks

Comment: The name of the MQ Service may vary. I'm using the default dev installation setup and the name was "IBM MQ (Installation1)".

Answer (score 0):

You can try supplying user/password in the `runmqsc` command running `runmqsc -u user1`.